# Case Sensitive search when using Excel as database

Tags: sql, excel, case-sensitive

I am unable to do a case sensitive search when using Excel as a database.
For eg, if the Col1 contains data like this

```
Data
DATA
DATa
daTA
```

and I perform a query like

```
Select * 
from [Sheet1$] 
where Col1 = 'Data'
```

it will retrieve all the four records.

Even using Like statement does not work.

If I give `Select * from [Sheet1$] where Col1 like 'Data%'` still retrieves all the four records.

The COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS option is only for SQL server and does not work for Excel. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I do not need the UCASE/ UPPER/ LCASE/ LOWER functions as most of my data is in mixed case, similar to the example I have given above.

Is it possible to create a query to retrieve the data in a case -sensitive fashion ,like retrieve only Data or DATA or daTA record when I query for them?

NOTE
I am using Excel 2007 .xlsx as the database and Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 as the Provider.

Comment: `where lower(col1) = 'data'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [COLLATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) (not sure if it works for excel)

```
Select * 
from [Sheet1$] 
where Col1 = 'Data'
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS  // CS = Case Sensitive
```

or

```
Select * 
from [Sheet1$] 
where Col1 = 'Data'
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  // CI = Case Insensitive
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046.aspx) for information on [Windows Collations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046.aspx).